# window.event fails when called from setTimeout

Tags: javascript, events, settimeout

I have a page that will perform actions based on the value of a cookie. When the page loads, I want to halt these actions by holding the shift key.

```
function checkForShift() {
    if (window.event.shiftKey) {
        alert('Shift key detected, aborting');
        return false
    }
    else {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

This works great, unless I call checkForShift() from a setTimeout() function.  Like so:

```
setTimeout ( "checkForShift()" , 500 );
```

In this case, the checkForShift() function is called after 500ms, but the next line fails with this message:

```
Unable to get property 'shiftKey' of undefined or null reference
```

Why is it undefined when called from setTimeout() ?

Comment: How is `checkForShift` called normally?

Answer (score 2):

The event is only valid when it occurs (and don't use `window.event` but the even provided to the event handling callback).

To properly achieve what you want, you must store the state by detecting its changes :

```
var shiftKeyDown = false;
window.onkeydown = function(e){
    shiftKeyDown = !!(e||window.event).shiftKey;
}
window.onkeyup = function(){
    shiftKeyDown = false;
}
function checkForShift() {
    if (shiftKeyDown) {
        alert('Shift key detected, aborting');
    } else {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

And when you call `setTimeout`, don't pass a string but a function :

```
setTimeout (checkForShift , 500 );
```

Comment: You said don't use `window.event` but you used it!

Comment: @JuanMendes That was obviously a typo. Fixed.

Comment: argument e is not available for all browsers. you need a cross-browser check to it.

Comment: easy question... IE? you could have guess that.

Comment: As far as I know, the cross browser way is to do `function handler(e) { e = e || window.event}`. I believe IE 9 is the first one that doesn't need `window.event`

Comment: @Juno [I found a reference mentioning the version](http://help.dottoro.com/ljogqtqm.php). It turns out you're right, `window.event` is needed for IE8.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `event` or `window.event` from `setTimeout` callbacks. You have to detect the shift key on your own using `onkeydown` and `onkeyup`.

```
// Modified version of dystroy's code
var shiftKeyDown = false;
function setShift(e) {
    e = e || window.event; // For IE < 9
    shiftKeyDown = !!e.shiftKey;
}
function checkForShift() {
    if (shiftKeyDown) {
        alert('Shift key detected, aborting');
    } else {
        //do stuff
    }
}
window.onkeydown = window.onkeyup = setShift;
setTimeout(checkForShift, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

An `event` object is being removed by browser engine when the event handling cycle is completed.

Since `setTimeout` is always asynchronous, the event object is not available anymore.

Besides, `window.event` property is not cross-browser. You should use event library or write your own cross-browser event wrapper for this.

```
function (e) {
    if (!e) { e = window.event; }
    // do whatever you want with event object
}
```